# Mixed languages in bash after OS X update to El Capitan

Tags: bash, locale

In my user, which has admin privileges, I have several languages enabled, and `English (U.S.)` is the 'Primary' language:

[image: language settings]

After updating to El Capitan (10.11), I get mixed languages in `bash`:

```
$ svn up
Updating '.':                     [English]
På revisjon 3096.                 [Norwegian]
$ lk
bash: lk: команда не найдена      [Russian]
$
```

Each message is reliably the same language every time. `Command not found` is always in Russian, `On revision ####` is always in Norwegian, etc. I know these languages, so this isn't impacting my productivity, but what the dad gum is going on?!

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What does `echo "$LANGUAGE"` say? GNU's gettext checks that variable for language settings/priority list too. Perhaps you are looking at partial translations and fallbacks.

Comment: @Arthur2e5 `$LANGUAGE` is empty. It's been a few months since I asked the question, and sometime since then, the problem seems to have resolved itself. I only just noticed when you commented. I know that I have run `port upgrade outdated` a few times since then, so any number of utilities could have been upgraded. I really wish that I knew what had happened. I don't like mysteries when computers are involved. :(